# How to create datacontract which holds runtime column returning from stored procedure

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008-r2, datacontract

Need help defining a `DataContract` for a `WCF` Service when stored procedure returns the dynamic columns.Please see image as shown in link for better understanding my scenario [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlEvH.png) .

In this scenario my stored procedure returns subjects(Columns) which may vary.

Please advise how to write/create data contract?

Platform - Silver light, MVVM Framework

Comment: Need more information , which platform are you using to consume this WCF service??

Comment: IMO its not possible to create dynamic data contract, possible solution in this case is to find out what maximum no of subjects are generated and create datacontract according it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to accomplish a similar goal, in which I needed to display a dynamic data set in a grid.  To accomplish I returned a list of dictionaries.

```
    [OperationContract]
    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>> GetSourceDataAll(string sBatchId);
```